# How to restrict an iframe to a single line of a document (another web page)

Tags: html, wordpress, iframe, customization

Im trying to display a dynamically changing number that is part of another web page (non of my domains) within my wordpress blog. I have already downloaded a plugin so wordpress doesnt delete iframes as usual from the editor. I can display the iframe on my wordpress blog fine as well. But I ONLY want to display one line of text (that one number) and not the entire page (so the dimensions of the iframe would be something like heigt "50px" width "100px" or similar, no scrollbars). So how can i determine what is displayed inside the iframe?
Below is a sample code thats still missing the ability to pick the part of the website I want to show and crop the rest:

```
[iframe src="https://XXXXXXXX.com/" width="100" height="50" scrolling="no" style="margin-left:300px;"]
```

Thank you

Answer (score -1):

That is not possible.
The iframe will pull in the whole content of the target page.

Comment: The question says "another web page (non of my domains)" — attempts to use JS to do that will raise a security exception.